# Unit testing legacy php application — how to prevent unexpected database calls

Tags: php, mysql, database, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm adding unit tests to a legacy PHP application that uses a MySQL compatible database. I want to write genuine unit tests that don't touch the database.

How should I avoid accidentally using a database connection?

Lots of parts of the application use static method calls to get a reference to a database connection wrapper object. If I'm looking at one of these calls I know how to use dependency injection and test doubles to avoid hitting the database from a test, but I'm not sure what to do about all the database queries that I'm not looking at at any one time, which could be some way down the call stack from the method I'm trying to test.

I've considered adding a public method to the database access class that would be called from the PHPUnit bootstrap file and set a static variable to make any further database access impossible, but I'm not keen on adding a function to the application code purely for the sake of the tests that would be harmful if called in production.

Comment: What's wrong with database calls in your unit tests? If the function of that unit is to read or write from the database you'll need to do that. If not, the database shouldn't be an issue. Look at how frameworks do it: Usually they employ a test database schema that's cloned from the development one to verify functionality.

Comment: Stubbing out your entire database will be a huge undertaking and probably an even bigger mistake.

Comment: @tadman A unit test is a test that exercises one unit of code in isolation from all of its dependencies. A test that interacts with the database is not a database.

Comment: @bdsl Adding unit tests after the fact into a legacy codebase usually is painful at least and impossible at worst. I would suggest characterization tests implemented as integration tests or end-to-tests to bring your legacy application under test. From there you can refactor it into smaller, manageable modules that can be unit-tested.

Comment: @SebastianBergmann It depends on how strict a definition you're going to go by. Theoretically, yes. Pragmatically, no. If your code's job is to save into and load from a database and you only test that vs. a mock you're not really testing anything.

Answer (score 4):

Adding tests to a legacy application can be delicate, especially unit tests. The main problem you will likely have is that most tests will be hard to write and easily become unintelligible, because they involve massive amount of setting up and mocking. At the same time you will likely not have much freedom to refactor them, so they become easier to test, because that will lead to ripple effects in the code base.

That's why I usually prefer end to end-tests. You can cover lots of ground without having to test close to the implementation and those tests are usually more useful when you want to do large scale refactoring or migrate the legacy code base later, because you ensure that the most important features you were using still work as expected.

For this approach you will need to test through the database, just not the live database. In the beginning it's probably easiest to just make a copy, but it's absolutely worthwhile to create a trimmed down database with some test fixtures from scratch. You can then use something like selenium to test your application through the web interface by describing the actions you take on the site, like go to url x, fill out a form and submit it and describe the expected outcome, like I should be on url y now and there should be a new entry in the database. As you can see these kinds of tests are written very close to what you see on the website and not so much around the implementation or the single units. This is actually intended because in a migration you might want to rip out large chunks and rewrite them. The unit tests will become completely useless then, because the implementation might change drastically, but those end2end-tests describing the functionality of the site will still remain valid.

There are multiple ways you can go about this. If you are familiar with PHPUnit you might want to try the selenium-extension. You should find tutorials for this online, for example this one: https://www.sitepoint.com/using-selenium-with-phpunit/

Another popular option for these kind of tests is [Behat](http://behat.org/) with the [MinkExtension](http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/). In both cases the hardest part is setting up selenium, but once you are able to write a simple test, that for example goes to your frontpage and checks for some text snippet and get that running. You can write tests really fast.

One big downside of these tests is that they are very slow, because they do full web requests and in some cases have to do some waiting for JavaScript. So you should probably not test everything. Instead try to focus on the most important features. If you have some e-commerce project, maybe go through a very generic checkout procedure. Then expand on different variations that are important to you, e.g. logged in user vs. new user or adding vouchers to the basket. Another good way to start is write very stupid tests, that just check whether your urls are actually accessible, so go to url and check for status code and some expected text snippet. Those are not really that useful in terms of making sure your application behaves correctly, but they still give you some safety as to whether some random 500 errors appear out of the blue.

This is probably the best approach for making safe your app works well and make it easier to upgrade, refactor or migrate your application or parts of it. Additionally whenever you add new features, try to write some actual unit tests for them. It's probably easiest if they are not too connected with the old parts of the code. In the best case scenario you won't have to worry too much about the database, because you can replace the data you get from the database with some instances you prepare yourself in the test and then just test whatever feature. Obviously if it's something like a simple we want to have a form that adds this data to the database, you will probably still not want to write a unit test, but instead write one of those bigger end to end-tests instead.